# C++ angled brackets (templates) followed by double colon

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm looking at the following code:

```
template <typename T, typename Tag>
class __attribute__((trivial_abi)) OSTaggedSharedPtr: public libkern::intrusive_shared_ptr<T, intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<Tag> > {
    using libkern::intrusive_shared_ptr<T, intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<Tag> >::intrusive_shared_ptr;
};
```

I understand there is a new class `OSTaggedSharedPtr` which inherits from `libkern::instrusive_shared_ptr`. I am unsure what the template after the inheritance does, specifically this part: `<T, intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<Tag> >` .
The same confusion applies to the using lib `kern::intrusive_shared_ptr` template, specifically `<T, intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<Tag> >`. I'm pretty sure this has been answered, but I can't find the right wording for the question in google, so sorry about that.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Comment: instrusive_shared_ptr is a template class https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/

Answer (score 0):

> I am unsure what the template after the inheritance does, specifically this part: `<T, intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<Tag> >` .

You already understood that `OSTaggedSharedPtr` inherits from `libkern::intrusive_shared_ptr`. So far, so good.

Now `libkern::intrusive_shared_ptr` itself is a template class, **too**. The `<T, intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<Tag> >` part are the template parameters of  `libkern::intrusive_shared_ptr`. To make things a bit more complicated, those in turn contain a template, too. `intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer` is a template with the template parameter `Tag`.

Now we know that [templates can be template parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/templates-cpp?view=msvc-160#template_parameters), too.

Your code snippet basically has templates all over the place. It can be a bit confusing at first, but that is not unusual in C++ code, e. g. in the STL.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand there is a new class `OSTaggedSharedPtr` which inherits from `libkern::instrusive_shared_ptr`.

Not quite. It would appear that `libkern::instrusive_shared_ptr` is a template, not a class, so inheritance as you describe is not possible. Rather, the inheritance is from the class resulting from instantiating the template using the template arguments `T` and `intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<Tag>`. That is, there is inheritance from `libkern::instrusive_shared_ptr<T, intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<Tag> >` (the full expression; don't try to chop off the part delimited by angles brackets).

To make this more complicated (but easier to work with), `OSTaggedSharedPtr` is also a template, not a class. When `OSTaggedSharedPtr` is instantiated, two template arguments are required, `T` and `Tag`. So a more accurate description of this scenario is that there is a new family of classes, `OSTaggedSharedPtr<T,Tag>`, each of which inherits from the corresponding `libkern::instrusive_shared_ptr<T, intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<Tag> >`.

**Examples**

`libkern::instrusive_shared_ptr` is a template, while
`libkern::instrusive_shared_ptr<int, intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<int> >` is a class defined via the template.

`OSTaggedSharedPtr` is a template, while
`OSTaggedSharedPtr<int, int>` is a class resulting from that template, and that class inherits from the class in the above example (`libkern::instrusive_shared_ptr<int, intrusive_tagged_osobject_retainer<int> >`).

Comment: sorry i deleted my last comment that said libkern::intrusive_shared_ptr is a template class, you are correct, it is actually a struct which defines some variables, functions, and classes